# ReactJS child elements manipulate child elements in 1 component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, reactive-programming

I'm a React newbie here, have been working with Jquery for a long time. So cant get use to the React/Redux style.

I have been stuck with child elements try handle another child elements function for a while.

```
{this.state.stocks.map(function(data, index) {

    return (
        <div className={"list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start"} key={index}>

          <div className={"d-flex w-100 justify-content-between"} onClick={this.handleToggle}>
            <h5 className="mb-1">
                <span className={styles.symbolTitle}>Stock Symbol:</span> <span className={styles.symbolName}>{data.symbol}</span> ${data.price}&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button type="button" className={"btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm "+ styles.btnTrans +""} >more...</button>
            </h5>
            <small>
              {this.state.shares}&nbsp;
              <span className={styles.colorGrey}>shares</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button type="button" className={"btn btn-outline-success btn-sm "+ styles.btnTrans +""} onClick={this.handleBuy}>Buy</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button type="button" className={"btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm "+ styles.btnTrans +""} onClick={this.handleSell}>Sell</button>
            </small>
          </div>

          <div className={stateStyle}>
              <small>Open Price: {data.open}</small>&nbsp;
              <small>Highest Price: {data.high}</small>&nbsp;
              <small>Lowest Price: {data.low}</small>&nbsp;
              <small>All Price: {(data.low + data.high).toFixed(2)}</small>&nbsp;
              <small>Volume: {data.volume}</small>&nbsp;
              <small>Average Volume: {data.average_volume}</small>&nbsp;
              <small>Volatility: {data.volatility}</small>
          </div>

        </div>
     )
}.bind(this))}
```

Like I attached above, its a series loop of divs. I'm trying to simple toggle the sibling div on the div who has onClick function. However, what I got so far is the function handleToggle will toggle all the divs which been generated under the map function. The toggle function is below:

```
 handleToggle: function() {
    if (this.state.active) {
      this.setState({
        active: false
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        active: true
      })
    }
  },
```

Not sure what to do next. Can you guys give me some insights?

Comment: what do you mean by `toggle` all the div. and what are you doing the state `active` which is modified ?

Comment: @Panther As you can see there are 2 divs within 1 parent. the first child div has a onClick, I was trying to use that Div(as a button) to toggle the next child(sibling). The active state is just a handler to modify the show/hide

Comment: can you have multiple `child` div be open at the same time ?

Comment: no, its more like 1 button target the corresponding div within the parent (also a sibling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handleRowToggle(key)` will toggle all objects that are related to the `key` value.

`handleButtonBuy(key)` will increment the key `buyCount` value stored in state.

```js
const data = [
        { id: 1, title : 'test1', value1: 'value11', value2: 'value21', buyCount: 0},
        { id: 2, title : 'test2', value1: 'value21', value2: 'value22', buyCount: 5},
        { id: 3, title : 'test3', value1: 'value31', value2: 'value32', buyCount: 10}
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      stocks: data
    }
  }

  handleRowToggle(key) {
    var allKeyRecords = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-toggle="${key}"]`);
    allKeyRecords.forEach(record => record.classList.toggle('hide'))
  }
  
  handleButtonBuy(key) {
    this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
      const stocks = prevState.stocks.map(stock => {
        if (stock.id === key) {
          stock.buyCount++;
        }
        return stock;
      });
      // New state console logged
      console.log(stocks);
      
      // ES6 it's the same as stocks: stocks
      return {
        stocks
      };
    }); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <StockList 
          stocks={this.state.stocks}
          handleRowToggle={this.handleRowToggle.bind(this)}
          handleButtonBuy={this.handleButtonBuy.bind(this)}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class StockList extends React.Component {
  renderList() {
    return this.props.stocks.map((stock) => {
      return (
        <tr
          key={stock.id}
          >
          <td data-toggle={stock.id}>
            {stock.id}
          </td>
          <td data-toggle={stock.id}>
            {stock.title}
          </td>          
          <td data-toggle={stock.id}>
            {stock.value1}
          </td>
          <td data-toggle={stock.id}>
            {stock.value2}
          </td>             
           <td data-toggle={stock.id}>
            {stock.buyCount}
          </td> 
          <td data-toggle={stock.id}>
            <button onClick={ (event) => this.props.handleButtonBuy(stock.id) }>Buy Me</button>
          </td> 
          <td>
            <button onClick={ (event) => this.props.handleRowToggle(stock.id) }>Toggle Row</button>
          </td>              
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <tbody>
        {this.renderList()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}






ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
tr td.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think thats what I was looking for! I will modify my code to adjust. Will let you know the result later

Comment: Sure, let me know if it suits you

Comment: I'm on my way of changing from es5 to es6.. real pain in the ass. ugh

Comment: I am glad I could help you. ES6 is great, it will improve your development. Could you mark my answer so the others can see it too?

Comment: Yeah i already did. but somehow Stackoverflow told me I dont have enough reputation to mark it :(

Comment: Hi loelsonk, I have another quick question similar with this toggle function. I have another state in the same child div here. I set with shares bought/sold. What i was trying to achieve is every time user click the buy button, the share state increase by 1 (vice versa with sold) But somehow I can have this Buy button hooked to its correspond sibling div(child div). whenever i click it changes all the states (since theres a loop through parsing 1 json object)

Comment: I'm sure theres a method/structure to handle these kinda situations. Can you let me know where to look?

Comment: Which I mean whenever theres a tons of siblings (loop) the state I set up with only affect its own div (child/sibling).Not like it will affect everything at once

Comment: Would you like to have a buy button in each row, and extend current state to something like this?  `{name : 'test1', value1: 'value11', value2: 'value21', boughtCount: 10 }` ( I've added `boughtCount` key.) So when each time user clicks a buy button, `boughtCount` is increased for that state object?

Comment: you mean store the boughtCount in the server side? in my case its a RestAPI i create with MERN

Comment: and yes I do have a buy button in each row

Comment: Do you want an example with only updating the state or props + actionCreator + Redux? There is not much sense in keeping it in state. I understand each row/record is stored in database and you want to update database instead of updating only state.

Comment: yes, thats what I was looking for in the first place. I didnt find a good example. can you link me a tutorial or something? very much appreciated

Comment: I've updated my example. See it now - I've added new functionality. I've learned a lot from `Stephen Grider's` tutorials at udemy. These are paid tutorials you can buy them for 10 dollars/euro in promotion week. You should defenitely check some youtube vids first about react and of course read the excellent react documentation.

Comment: I see what you doing here. You have separated the big block (which I had before) into components piece by piece. And then passing the states to each other by using bind(). Yeah I'm gonna def take few course on reactjs with ES6. thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `active` from the `state` to optionally display elements. Something like:

```
{this.state.stocks.map(function(data, index) {
   const summary = (
      <div className={stateStyle}>
          <small>Open Price: {data.open}</small>&nbsp;
          <small>Highest Price: {data.high}</small>&nbsp;
          <small>Lowest Price: {data.low}</small>&nbsp;
          <small>All Price: {(data.low + data.high).toFixed(2)}</small>&nbsp;
          <small>Volume: {data.volume}</small>&nbsp;
          <small>Average Volume: {data.average_volume}</small>&nbsp;
          <small>Volatility: {data.volatility}</small>
      </div>
   )

   return (
      <div className={"list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start"} key={index}>

        <div className={"d-flex w-100 justify-content-between"} onClick={this.handleToggle}>
          <h5 className="mb-1">
              <span className={styles.symbolTitle}>Stock Symbol:</span> <span className={styles.symbolName}>{data.symbol}</span> ${data.price}&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button type="button" className={"btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm "+ styles.btnTrans +""} >more...</button>
          </h5>
          <small>
            {this.state.shares}&nbsp;
            <span className={styles.colorGrey}>shares</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="button" className={"btn btn-outline-success btn-sm "+ styles.btnTrans +""} onClick={this.handleBuy}>Buy</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="button" className={"btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm "+ styles.btnTrans +""} onClick={this.handleSell}>Sell</button>
          </small>
        </div>

        { this.state.active && summary }

      </div>
   )
}.bind(this))}
```

This will only render the `summary` elements (feel free to pick a more appropriate name) if `this.state.active` is `true`.